# Cannot implement __lt__ operator

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I have a class `Quantity` and I want to implement the `__lt__` operator to overload. I have implemented the method as shown below.

```
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Quantity):
            return other.value < self.value
        if isinstance(other, numbers.Real):
            return self.value < other
        raise NotImplemented
```

When I import it into the python console and try to execute it

```
>>> Quantity(1.2) > 1
```

I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'number'
```

And if I try to execute it like this

```
>>> Quantity(1.2) < 1
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Quantity' and 'int'
```

Does anyone know how can I implement the overload to work with `<` and `>`?

**Update**

Here is the full class

```
class Quantity:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = float(value)

    def __float__(self):
        return self.value

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Quantity({})'.format(self.value)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)


   def __lt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Quantity):
            return other.value < self.value
        if isinstance(other, numbers.Real):
            return self.value > other
        raise NotImplemented

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        value = round(value, 10)
        self._value = int(value * 1000) / 1000.0
```

Comment: What is `Quantity`? What are `numbers`? Also, your first `if` statement will return `True` if `self.value` is *greater* than `other.value`

Comment: For me the first raise the exception, and the second works, please check again

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/SlategrayNovelProject

Comment: @C.Nivs I updated the post so the whole class is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error on `Quantity(1.2) > 1` because you have not defined [`__gt__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__gt__) for your `Quantity` class. As pointed out, you also have an error in your `__lt__` method and perform the comparison the wrong way around (`other.value < self.value` rather than `self.value < other.value`). I believe this should work:

```
def __lt__(self, other):                                                    
    if isinstance(other, Quantity):                                         
        return self.value < other.value                                     
    if isinstance(other, numbers.Real):                                     
        return self.value < other                                           
    raise NotImplemented                                                    

def __gt__(self, other):                                                    
    if isinstance(other, Quantity):                                         
        return self.value > other.value                                     
    if isinstance(other, numbers.Real):                                     
        return self.value > other                                           
    raise NotImplemented
```

Your second example, `Quantity(1.2) < 1` should work. The error message you quote on that one is not reproducible, it seems (I checked python 2.7 and 3.8).